# New corned beef ideas

Tags: beef, corn

I love beef especially corned beef but i would like to try a new version or recipe like i know how to slow cook it or make a Ruben with it but there isn't a whole lot in the way of variations. So how about something new like glazing with honey or marinating it in pineapple juice to tenderize it?

Comment: Welcome to the site @CopperTopp. I'm afraid your question is off topic as it's a recipe request, it's also very opinion based. I would suggest going to the help center for guidance on questions.

Comment: I agree. As written, this question is off-topic. See the [tour](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/help) for more.

Answer (score 1):

In a sing sing base,][ Australian stile, shred, fry with onions. Serve with rice. Freeze-cold chill till firm. Slice very thin. Or use meat cutter. 1/8 inch thick. Braze brown both sides on a hot flat plate,grill. Stack with peppers black or hot. Or other things between each. Refrigerate over night. Or a soysauce mix? vinegar mix? what ever. Slap between a roll the next day. For sandwich.